# How to get IP address of Computer when running React Native app?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to build an app which can get IP address of computer when running app. I have found **react-native-public-ip** but seems like that it gets IP address of the virtual device. So Is there anyway I can get IP address of computer?

Answer (score 2):

`react-native-network-info` is a good option but you can also you [`react-native-netinfo`](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-netinfo)

Migrating from the core react-native module

This module was created when the NetInfo was split out from the core of React Native. To migrate to this module you need to follow the [installation instructions](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-netinfo) and then change you imports from:

`import { NetInfo } from "react-native";`

to:

`import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo";`

**Usage**

Import the library:

`import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo";`

Get the network state once:

```
NetInfo.fetch().then(state => {
  console.log("Connection type", state.type);
  console.log("Is connected?", state.isConnected);
});
```

Subscribe to network state updates:

```
// Subscribe
const unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
  console.log("Connection type", state.type);
  console.log("Is connected?", state.isConnected);
});

// Unsubscribe
unsubscribe();
```

**API**

Types:

```
NetInfoState
NetInfoStateType
NetInfoCellularGeneration
```

Methods:

```
fetch()
addEventListener()
useNetInfo()
```

You're good to go!! 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

React Native library for getting information about the `devices network`

You can use `react-native-network-info`

**Example.js**

```js
import { NetworkInfo } from "react-native-network-info";

// Get Local IP
const ipAddress = await NetworkInfo.getIPAddress();

// Get IPv4 IP
const ipv4Address = await NetworkInfo.getIPV4Address();

// Get Broadcast
const broadcast = await NetworkInfo.getBroadcast();
```